# Java Applet how do I update a textfield?

Tags: java, applet, textfield

So I want to do this Frame and run it as an applet later.

This is my code in short. I want every time I click on a new item from the Choice list to have my text field updated to the selected item name.

This is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
class Exercitiul3 extends Frame implements ItemListener{

   Choice c = new Choice();  
   TextField t;


public Exercitiul3(){

        c.setBounds(10,40,200,60); 
        c.addItemListener(this);


        c.add("Articol 1");  
        c.add("Articol 2");  
        c.add("Articol 3");  
        c.add("Articol 4");  
        c.add("Articol 5");  

        t = new TextField(c.getSelectedItem());
        t.setBounds(10,100, 200,30);


        add(c);
        add(t);
        setSize(220,150);  
        setLayout(null);  
        setVisible(true); 
        addWindowListener(new WA()); 

}

    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {


    }




class WA extends WindowAdapter
{    
public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
{System.exit(0); }
}

public static void main(String[]args){ 
    new Exercitiul3();
}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by updating a text-field?

Comment: You can get the selected item from the event with `e.getItem()`.

Comment: By updating the text field I mean changing the text within every time I select a new item from my Choice list. As you can see I bound the textfield to the Choice list here:   t = new TextField(c.getSelectedItem());

Comment: *"As you can see I bound the textfield to the Choice list"* Nope. That merely instantiates the text field using the currently selected value of the combo box. It does not 'bind' the text field to show future updates to the combo. **General tips:** 1) Why use AWT?   See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255106/java-gui-listeners-without-awt/6255978#6255978) for many good reasons to abandon AWT components in favor of Swing. 2) Applets have become completely unworkable for sites dealing to 'all comers' on the internet.  ..

Comment: .. Safari and FF both block applets by default, and Chrome and IE are set to completely remove support for them.  It is best to transition away from applets to pure JS/HTML sooner rather than later. 3) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556). ..

Comment: .. 4) Tip: Add @am0awad (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.